# Passing parameter from textfield in on one jframe to another jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jtextfield

I'm trying to simply create four jtextfields and a jbutton. Once the button is pushed, i want the text inputted into the jtextfields to be passed as parameters (p, var, s, f) to another window to which displays a mathematical function using the parameters given.

I don't want this second window to show up and display a mathematical function until the initial button was pushed.

How can I do this? I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but I'm learning..

So far, I have graphing part done, and so all I need to do now is create the first window with the textboxes and buttons which link to the graphing window.

Here is the beginning of the code that I think is worth showing so you know which variables I'm talking about:

```
public class Cartesian {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    CartesianFrame frame = new CartesianFrame();
    frame.showUI();

   }
  });
 }

}

class CartesianFrame extends JFrame {
 CartesianPanel panel;

 public CartesianFrame() {
  panel = new CartesianPanel();
  add(panel);

 }

 public void showUI() {
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setTitle("Polynomial Grapher");
  setSize(700, 700);
  setVisible(true);
 }
}

class CartesianPanel extends JPanel {
    //These are the variables I want to be assigned to textfields(I'm assuming      using "gettext" from another window.

     String p="something from textbox one";//Variable 1
     String var="something from textbox two";//Variable 2
     double s=-2;//ANY double value from textbox 3
     double f=2;//ANY double value from textbox 4
```

...
...
...
The rest of the code used after this is just a paint component, etc. which is used to display the cartesian plane and the mathematical function.

I've looked on the web for some other examples, but they haven't applied to what I'm doing.. I'm interested in any feedback! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Don't create a second JFrame. If you absolutely must show a second window, show a dialog such as a JDialog or JOptionPane. As to how to do this, simply create a JPanel that displays the information that you'd like to show the user, perhaps in a JLabel, and then show it in a JOptionPane using its `showMessage(...)` method. It's pretty easy, actually.

If this doesn't help, then you'd better tell us more about exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you for such a fast response, I think I explained my question incorrectly. Those variables " String p="x*(x+1)*(x+3)*x*x";//Variable 1
     String var="b";//Variable 2
     double s=-2;//Variable 3
     double f=2;//Variable 4" are just the variables that Im playing around with, and I want the user to supply that info rather than me.  I don't even necessarily have to have a second jframe, I just need to have the text fields and button available to the user to type into and press (possibly on the same frame as the functions being graphed)

Comment: To explain more about where I'm lost, I'm confused as to how I can communicate the user inputted strings (which are inputted into the textfields) with the paint component that acquires the users inputs and draws accordingly (given the users information).

Comment: @user1854787: When the user presses his JButton, you extract the text from the JTextFields in the button's ActionListener. I'm sure that you've read the tutorials on this, and if so, what step exactly has you stuck?

Comment: So for not being clear enough,hopefully my other post can explain where exactly I'm stuck..                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13598788/action-listener-repaint-not-working